# Splitting 150amp Service (midwire) from home at 100amps

Tags: electrical, wiring

How do I split 150 amp wire to have a hundred amp service continued in the house and at 80 amps to a separate cabin?

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please describe your scenario in more detail *in your question body*.

Comment: The distance between the buildings and service would be helpful also.

Comment: When you say 'midwire' do you mean you want to cut into the physical cable somewhere between your house and the utility? Normally you'd run the cabin as a subpanel, serviced from a breaker on your main panel in your house -- is there some reason you can't do that? The size of wire needed is dependent on current (80 amps) and distance.

Comment: If tapped the wire size would need to be full sized to the new panel. This would also require a box at the tap location and listed underground splice and sealing methods.

Comment: So we have the Maine Pole and it runs from irea 150 amps to the house breaker. The breaker box is not to be messed with because it is a very bad box so I would like to cut the wire just outside of the house and I need to be able to split the power meaning have 150 amps coming in and 100 amps going out to the house and 80 amps going out to the other units. Once it is split at the house they will be another box that the 80 amp breaker will be in.

Comment: We're talking no more than a 30 foot span here from the cut wire at the house.

Comment: We will not be running more than the allowed amount, the house will only run at most 50 amps I just want to keep the box at 100 amps so I don't have to mess with any of the wires. The other units will probably run 60 to 70 amps. I will not be pulling the full 150amps at one time

Comment: @MilesStone it helps greatly if you EDIT the info you have just provide in 3 comments into your original question.  Who does that help? It helps you, because your question will get renewed attention on the active page, comments won't do that.

Comment: The NEC requires residential panels to be at least 100 amps

Comment: @EdBeal can you cite the section of NEC that requires 100 amp panels?

Comment: Will the cabin have other people living in it?  Where in the world are you?  What size are the existing service conductors? It sounds like you're talking about service feeder taps, however, in my opinion that's a bit beyond even an experienced  DIYers abilities. It might be worth calling in an Electrician, at least to get the taps installed properly.

Comment: @Tester101 Doesn't 310.15(B)(7) suggest a 100 apm minimum  by saying *For a service rated 100 through 400 amperes ...* and listing no service below 100?

Comment: 2014 NEC 230.79.C One-Family Dwellings. The service disconnecting means shall have a rating of not less than 100 amperes, 3-wire. Also, 225.39.C. I think it may be in a couple more places but there are 2 places.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to avoid touching the existing panel.

The closest you can come is installing a new main panel where you cut your feeder. Then power the existing main panel from the new panel; your existing panel becomes a subpanel. However, you will need to remove the neutral/ground bonding from the old panel, and depending on how your ground rod is connected to the old panel you will have to move it to the new panel. And because you've now touched the old panel, it likely can not be excluded from permitting and inspection, and if it's as bad as you imply, then you'll have to fix it.

And since you're now in a position where you have to fix your old panel, forget about fixing the old panel. Instead, replace it. And run an 80 amp branch circuit from the new panel to your other house.

Comment: I'm not sure it's that simple.

Comment: Agreed. My point was that doing this without violating the "The breaker box is not to be messed with because it is a very bad box" constraint is likely impossible.